Not showing email content in Message & Details tab in EmailMessage record
As a System Administrator, I can see all the contents(From,To,Html Body and so on) in Message & Details tab in a EmailMessage record. But when login as other users, the Message & Details tab are in there, and the From & To also included in Message tab, but the email body not displaying in EmailMessage record in sandbox(As attached). Really appreciate on any feedback, thanks in advanced!
https://i.sstatic.net/KnnU0LoG.png

Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  Please provide more context; use [edit]. Like, what is different between users who can see the Body and those who can't

Finally I solved this issue by myself, and following is the steps for checking:

Please make sure the correct page layout for EmailMessage is using;
Set status equals to 3 when create new EmailMessage record;
Profile for EmailMessage object should have view permission for all
fields;

